# Pandas: plot the graph of unique values

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a column in pandas dataframe:

```
df.['A']:
1
1
1
2
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

I need to plot a histogram which will show how much if 1, of 2 and of 3 i have.
For that i firstly count the amount of all 1, 2, and 3:

```
print df.groupby(df.index)['A'].nunique()
```

but instead of getting

```
1   5
2   4
3   3
```

i get

```
1
1
1
```

what is my mistake? and may be there is a better way of plotting it withpout previous extraction of counted data?

Comment: Just like EdChum mentioned, for plotting the data, you can readily use the `hist()` method. If you actually wanted the counts of the values in a table, you can use `df.A.value_counts()`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

IIUC you can just call [`df['A'].hist()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.hist.html):

[image]

This will automatically plot the frequency of the unique values

Comment: Sorry you'll have to post data and code that demonstrates this error